# Can someone guide me when to use bind method over addListener in JavaFX(Java 8)? I find both quite similar

Tags: javafx, java-8

Basically I see bind method being used to adjust node dimensions relative to changes in Pane dimensions.
Also, I see sometimes addListener method in Java used in similar way.
So I am not able to understand when to prefer one over the other in case of JavaFX?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a change listener to an [`ObservableValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html) in order to carry out an arbitrary action when the value changes:

```
IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(42);
value.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    System.out.println("Value changed from "+oldValue+" to "+newValue));
```

One common requirement is to automatically change the value of one property when another changes. For this common, but specific, requirement, you can use a binding. Sometime bindings are simpler to code than listeners:

```
IntegerProperty valueTimesTwo = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
valueTimesTwo.bind(value.multiply(2));
```

and in other cases it's really just a choice of which you find clearer:

```
DoubleProperty logValuePlusOne = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

logValuePlusOne.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> Math.log(value.get()+1),
    value);

// or:
value.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    logValue.set(Math.log(newValue.intValue()+1)));
```

One advantage of the binding version above is that's it's a little easier to remove the binding:

```
logValuePlusOne.unbind();
```

Comment: And especially when you also consider bi-directional binding it becomes clear what the advantages of bindings are.

Answer (score 1):

While you can call `addListener()` on any class that implements `javafx.beans.Observable` (and there are tons of them), the `bind()` method is defined in the `javafx.beans.property.Property` class, which is way deeper in the hierarchy, and which itself extends the `Observable` interface.

So, `bind()` can be called only on classes that implement the `Property<T>` interface.  For subclasses of `javafx.beans.property.Property`, you can use either `bind()` or `addListener()`.

Two major advantages of `bind()` over `addListener()` are:

- All `bind()` calls in the `javafx` package are [implemented using weak listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-), while `addListener()` uses strong references. If you are not careful and do not remove all your listeners properly; the latter is prone to causing **memory leaks**, while the former is not.
- If your classes already implement the `Property` interface, you can create  bidirectional bindings, which is not possible with the observables.

So, I would strongly advocate use of `bind()` over `addListener()`